# How to add event listener when two views intersect?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm using Titanium studio for making a music game.I want to drag and drop image views in different spots and hear the audio when i drop that image view on that spot!

Answer (score 0):

You can check top, left, height, width value of the image and spot, when they are intersected, ring the tone:)

```
//I tought variables are defined.
if(!(img_top>spot_top+height) && !(img_top+height<spot_top) && 
   !(img_left>spot_left+width) && !(img_left+width<spot_left)
{
   //intersected action.
}
```